# NullPointerException Accessing EntityManagerFactory in Spring Boot Hibernate Application

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot - Hibernate application with a couple of entities. The application has a class that implements the ApplicationListener interface to load some data at startup. In this class, I autowire the EntityManagerFactory that is autoconfigured by Spring Boot (I assume) and use it to load the data, like so:

```
    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        entityManager.persist(…);
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    }
```

This works fine and the data is persisted to the database.
In the application itself, I have a Service class where I try to run a query against the database. However, when I autowire the EntityManagerFactory and try to use it, I get a NullPointerException:

```
@Autowired
private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

public ConcertEventResponse getEventInfo(ConcertEventRequest request) {
    ConcertEventResponse response = new ConcertEventResponse();

    // Get NullPointerException here!
    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    // Get NullPointerException here!

    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    String name = request.getArtistName();
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select a from Artist a where a.name = :name");
    query.setParameter("name", name);
    Artist artist = (Artist) query.getSingleResult();

    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    response.setArtist(artist);

    return response;
}
```

The class is annotated with @Service. I can use constructor-based injection to get a handle on EntityManagerFactory but don’t understand why I can autowire it in one place and not the other. What am I doing wrong? I am using H2 as my database, if that matters.

Comment: I see that "myMethod" does not have return type specified. Is it possible that "myMethod" is actually a constructor in your code?

Comment: My apologies. I was trying to make the method generic and forgot to add the return type. I have updated the question with the actual code. Thanks you for pointing this out!

Comment: How is your ComponentScan definition looks like? Does it include your Service class?

Comment: And how do you get and instance of the second bean at the first place? Is it @Autowired ? Or do you create it some other way? As per description looks like your second bean is outside of Spring's context.

Comment: Hello,
The application is a @SpringBootApplication. The service class (annotated with @Service) is in a package named “service” below the Spring Boot application like so:
+- example
     +- myapplication
         +- Application.java
         |
   +- bootstrap
         |   +- DataLoader.java
   |
         +- service
         |   +- EventService.java
         |   +- EventServiceImpl.java
         |
         +- entities
             +- Artist.java
             +- Event.java